# Compare CSV in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, csv, xslt-2.0

This is what I am trying to achieve:
I have a CSV file which has data like 1,4,5..and so on(not a fixed series) and I have an XML which is having certain node repeating. Now from that XML I need to remove all those nodes whose position is present in the the CSV file.

This is how I am trying to do it: 
I am passing the CSV file as  parameter to XSLT and calling a recursive template to print the XML. (Thanks to a post I had seen long time back..don't remember the address)

Problem: "This is not working"  :)

Below is my sample XML and XSLT. Any help would be appreciated.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Items>
    <Item IItemID="">
    </Item>
    <Item ItemID="100-8754">
    </Item>
    <Item ItemID="206-4141">
    </Item>
    <Item ItemID="">
    </Item>
</Items>
```

Here is the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes">
    <xsl:param name="ErrorPos" as="xs:string" select="'1,4'"/>
    <xsl:template match="*|/">
                <xsl:call-template name="commaSplit">
            <xsl:with-param name="dataString" select="$ErrorPos"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="position" select="1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="commaSplit">
        <xsl:param name="dataString"/>
        <xsl:param name="position"/>
            Vivek
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($dataString,',')">
                <!-- Select the first value to process -->
                <xsl:call-template name="getItems">
                    <xsl:with-param name="errorPosition" select="substring-before($dataString,',')"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$position"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <!-- Recurse with remainder of string -->
                <xsl:call-template name="commaSplit">
                    <xsl:with-param name="dataString" select="substring-after($dataString,',')"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$position + 1"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- This is the last value no need to  recurse -->
                <xsl:call-template name="getItems">
                    <xsl:with-param name="errorPosition" select="$dataString"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$position"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Process of individual value here -->
    <xsl:template name="getItems" match="/">
        <xsl:param name="errorPosition"/>
        <xsl:param name="position"/>
        <Items>
            <xsl:value-of select="$errorPosition"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(',',$position)"/><!--Just for testing...will be replaced by copy statement-->
        </Items>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Any reason why XSLT? As you're finding, XSLT doesn't know about CSV, which makes doing anything with CSV an absolute ballache. So it would be easier to do this through DOM manipulation in C#/Java/{language of chioce}.

Comment: Nope Chris...Actually we are not using C#..however I am not that much happy in JAVA , so if you could suggest any pointers for the same I would be happy to browse.

Comment: That's why I added {language of choice} to the list as pretty much every environmnet has an XML DOM parser these days, which is why I was asking why you're limiting yourself to XSLT.

Comment: so your looking to get  <Items><Item ItemID="100-8754">
    </Item>
    <Item ItemID="206-4141">
    </Item></Items>?

Comment: @ChrisJ: It seems that you aren't aware of XSLT 2.0. It was 5-6 years ago when people decided that using DOM was probably the worst possible choice of a number of alternatives for querying / processing XML.

Comment: @Dimitre ... I missed this was an XSLT 2 stylesheet. I am aware of it; I just haven't had chance to use it yet and it looks like MS's stack is being a bit tardy in support for it. Time to look for other libraries...

Comment: @Vivek: It may be a good idea to compare my answer with the currently accepted one. My answer uses essential features of XSLT 2.0/ XPath 2.0 and is much simpler and more than twice shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is because you have 2 templates which both match "/" the root of the xml document, in order to funnel the data correctly you must ensure a priority is set on the template you wish to execute first! since you are using named templates you can simply remove the match attribute off the getItems template!

with this minor change it works, unless you have a different output desired?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes">
    <xsl:param name="ErrorPos" as="xs:string" select="'1,4'"/>
    <xsl:template match="*|/" priority="999">
                <xsl:call-template name="commaSplit">
            <xsl:with-param name="dataString" select="$ErrorPos"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="position" select="1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="commaSplit">
        <xsl:param name="dataString"/>
        <xsl:param name="position"/>
            Vivek
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($dataString,',')">
                <!-- Select the first value to process -->
                <xsl:call-template name="getItems">
                    <xsl:with-param name="errorPosition" select="substring-before($dataString,',')"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$position"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <!-- Recurse with remainder of string -->
                <xsl:call-template name="commaSplit">
                    <xsl:with-param name="dataString" select="substring-after($dataString,',')"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$position + 1"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- This is the last value no need to  recurse -->
                <xsl:call-template name="getItems">
                    <xsl:with-param name="errorPosition" select="$dataString"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$position"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Process of individual value here -->
    <xsl:template name="getItems" match="/">
        <xsl:param name="errorPosition"/>
        <xsl:param name="position"/>
        <Items>
            <xsl:value-of select="$errorPosition"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(',',$position)"/><!--Just for testing...will be replaced by copy statement-->
        </Items>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Regards,
Sam

Comment: @Vivek, TreeMonkey: Why not really use XSLT 2.0 as the language it is intended to be? Using it as plain XSLT 1.0 is a shame.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I only know xslt 1.0 work in .net environment so little chance of this changing anytime soon, tho I have seen from your answers that for my purposes it could be very handy!

Comment: @Treemonkey: But both the OP's code and *your* answer is in XSLT 2.0??!?  If so, then we should write a true XSLT 2.0  code, not one that doesn't look like XSLT 2.0 and when seen and re-used by the readers is doing them a malservice.

Answer (score 3):

Good question, +1.

Note that you are using XSLT 2.0 but not any XSLT 2.0 - specific features at all.

**Here is a short and simple (single template, no recursion, no `xsl:call-template`, no `xsl:choose`, `xsl:when`, `xsl:otherwise`)**, *true* **XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pErrorPos" as="xs:string" select="'1,4'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDeletePos" as="xs:integer*" select=
 " for $s in tokenize($pErrorPos, ',')
    return xs:integer($s)
 "/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Item[position() = $vDeletePos]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Items>
    <Item IItemID=""/>
    <Item ItemID="100-8754"/>
    <Item ItemID="206-4141"/>
    <Item ItemID=""/>
</Items>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Items>
   <Item ItemID="100-8754"/>
   <Item ItemID="206-4141"/>
</Items>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Overriding the **[Identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.
2. Use of the standard XPath function **[`tokenize()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize)**.